# Why does finding a day distance from weekday y to weekday x in future direction have to be this complicated?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, c++20, libc++

In [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/chrono#L1911), this is the way we find days from weekday y (rhs) to weekday x (lhs) in future direction.

```
constexpr days operator-(const weekday& __lhs, const weekday& __rhs) noexcept
{
    const int __wdu = __lhs.c_encoding() - __rhs.c_encoding();
    const int __wk = (__wdu >= 0 ? __wdu : __wdu-6) / 7;
    return days{__wdu - __wk * 7};
}
```

The same as in [date.h](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h#L1816) library

```
CONSTCD14
inline
days
operator-(const weekday& x, const weekday& y) NOEXCEPT
{
    auto const wdu = x.wd_ - y.wd_;
    auto const wk = (wdu >= 0 ? wdu : wdu-6) / 7;
    return days{wdu - wk * 7};
}
```

I wonder why we can't do just only this?

```
return days{x.wd_ - y.wd_ >= 0 ? x.wd_ - y.wd_ : x.wd_ - y.wd_ + 7};
```

Comment: Those give the same results for all values in `[0,6]` for both, which is the only range that provides a specified result... seems like a question for Howard (who probably pays attention to several of these tags so should arrive forthwith)

Comment: Seems indeed similar and simpler. I also expect no performance losses in your version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rationale is that I wanted to offer some support for `weekday`s that are `!ok()`.  For example:

```
auto x = weekday{13} - weekday{5};  // x == 1d
```

I.e., for some range greater than [0, 6], the arithmetic is modulo 7.  This was an experiment, that I suppose is still in progress.  This support did not make it into the [C++20 spec](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.cal.wd.nonmembers#5).

Comment: Brilliant solution for wider use. Well, perhaps the commitees think there is some trade-off cycles there but I think this solution could eliminate tons way of "unspecified" use which makes itself more robust in some certain degrees Let's see whether other compiler would follow this or come up with other ideas.